# Сеть в Docker - и Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, docker, сеть

У меня машина с установленной Ubuntu 22.04, есть необходимость написать приложение на пайтон. Собственно последние пару дней я решаю поставленную себе задачу. До этого работал на маке, но мака болше нет, о чем слезы на щеках вот уже как две недели... Но не об этом история.
Я установил докер, запуска контейнер,все вроде бы хорошо...

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name postgres_db -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecret -d postgres:alpine
```

Проверка показывает:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS      NAMES
f101f4d17237   postgres:alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   5432/tcp   postgres_db
```

полет нормальный...

Но при попытке подлючения к базе данных при помощи pgAdmin или самого приложения  на 0.0.0.0:5432   или localhost:5432 я получаю ответ от:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

[image: постгрес говорит нет]

Я тогда поступаю следующим образом:

> > > `docker inspect postgres_db`
> > > и достаю адрес моего контейнера c запущенным postgres,который 127.17.0.2.

"Networks": {...

```
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

Я пробую подключится к адресу внутри докер сети и вуаля..." успешное подключение ".
Что не так в моем случае, я немного запутался... Буду рад получить почитать что нибудь на этот счет.
В документации сказано что нет необходимости настраивать что либо (bridge,network,forwarding) по мимо обычного запуска контейнеров. По крайней мере так всегда было когда я использовал мак. Причем инспектирую bridge

```
{
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
```

и он смотрит на 0.0.0.0 как и положено в общем...
Что может быть не так? Может это связано самими настройками Ubuntu?

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос результаты проверок: (а) выполняется ли докер: `docker ps | grep postgres`, (б) есть ли ошибки в логе докера `docker log postgres_db`, (в) какие порты открыты докером `sudo netstat -nplt | grep docker`. То, что соединение к адресу `0.0.0.0` не прошло - неудивительно, это несуществующий адрес. Странно, что не получилось подсоединиться к localhost

Comment: в логах написано нет ошибок, а нетстат показывает так       listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

Comment: Идеи закончились. Я запустил контейнер вашей командой и успешно подключился `psql -h localhost`. То есть у меня работает. BTW, `netstat` по-умолчанию показывает unix sockets. Для TCP нужно добавить флаг `-t`

Comment: ниже ответ добавил ) спасибо, про -t  - tcp, -u  - udp уже почитал )

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решен ! Возможно кто нибудь столкнется с такой же проблемой, по этому оставлю тут ...
Лучше указывать конкретно адрес который необходимо слушать. По крайней мере на маке у меня не было проблем с этим, на Ubuntu произошло. В случае бидла docker-compose вряд ли такое понадобится, но если вам надо запустить контейнер  для тестов, и настроек вне кластера, то наверное лучше указывать адрес конкретно.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 --name postgres_db -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecret -d postgres:alpine
```